# add items to map, collectively, one at a time, per attribute id

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have successfully been able to filter, for instance shakemaps, by attribute id - I have successfully achieved this multiple ways - but all ending with the same problem.

*1.)* with the where filter *2.)* definition expression *3.)* iterating through all attribute ids and bringing them back.

**The problem:** All exists for only allowing/displaying one per `attribute id` at a time.. my goal is to feed the `attribute ids` into a checkbox list (which I have done), but allowing for items via attribute id to be added to the map as they are checked, collectively, one at a time - currently I can not seem to get this to work with the aspect of having multiple or more then one appear at a time on the map.

**1.)** *i.e.* the below filter (attempted logic 1) & [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camerondevcam/pen/NWxroMN):

```
.....
         function filterByID(event) {
           const selectedID = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
             eqLayerView.filter = {
             where: "id = '" + selectedID + "'"
           };
         }

         view.whenLayerView(fl)
           .then(function(layerView) {

           eqLayerView = layerView;

           eqLayerView.filter = {
             where: "id = ''"
           };
.............
```

**2.)** *i.e.* another attempted logic (adding multiple at a time here, line by line, or via array):

```
layer.definitionExpression = "id = 'us70008jr5'",
layer.definitionExpression = "id = 'cgi988jr52'",
```

**3.)** *i.e.* 3rd attempt with a suggestion here on GIS exchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364578/loop-through-attribute-ids-of-featurelayer

```
layer
  .load()
  .then(() => {
    // create a query from the layer
    const query = layer.createQuery();
    query.returnDistinctValues = true;
    query.where = "grid_value > 2"; // or 1=1 if you need them all
    // the field you want distinct values for
    query.outFields = ["id"];
    return layer.queryFeatures(query);
  })
  .then(({ features }) => {
    // extract the ids to a list
    const ids = features.map(({ attributes }) => attributes.id);
    return ids;
  })
  .then((ids) => {
    // You can store them how you want, in this case,
    // I put them in a dropdown select menu
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    ids.forEach((id) => {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = id;
      option.innerText = id;
      fragment.appendChild(option);
    });
    list.appendChild(fragment);
    map.add(layer);
});
```

All attempted logic above result in the toggling of a shakemap by `attribute id` to be displayed only one at a time — by toggling a new on, the previous turns off, I need the ability to have multiple being able to exist on the map at once.

ArcGIS - javascript - 4.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure I answer this question a couple of weeks ago, but I can't find my answer so maybe I just thought I did, in that case sorry about that.

Anyway, with a couple of fixes your code should work. The main issue here I think is that your query is not correct if you are going to use checkboxs. You need to use a set query like `IN`. I would be fine if you use radio buttons.

Here you have your example with the fixes I mention,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <title>Filter features by attribute - 4.15</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css' />
  <script src='https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/'></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    require([
      'esri/views/MapView',
      'esri/Map',
      'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
      'esri/widgets/Expand'
    ], function (MapView, Map, FeatureLayer, Expand) {
      const layer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: 'https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/arcgis/rest/services/USGS_Seismic_Data_v1/FeatureServer/1/',
        outFields: ['*']
        , definitionExpression: 'eventTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND grid_value > 2'
      });
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: 'gray-vector'
        , layers: [layer]
      });

      const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        container: 'viewDiv',
        center: [-98, 40],
        zoom: 4
      });

      let eqLayerView;
      let selectedIDs = {};

      function updatedFilter() {
        const ids = [];
        for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(selectedIDs)) {
          if (value) {
            ids.push(`'${key}'`);
          }
        }
        eqLayerView.filter = {
          where: `id IN (${ids.join(',')})`
        };
        console.log(`[updateFilter] ${eqLayerView.filter.where}`);
      }

      const idElement = document.getElementById('id-filter');
      idElement.addEventListener('click', filterByID);
      function filterByID(event) {
        const chk = event.target;
        console.log(`[filterByID] ${chk.getAttribute('data-id')} ${chk.checked}`);
        selectedIDs[chk.getAttribute('data-id')] = chk.checked;
        updatedFilter();
      }

      view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function (layerView) {

        eqLayerView = layerView;
        updatedFilter();

        var query = layer.createQuery();
        query.outFields = ['id'];
        query.returnDistinctValues = true;
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        layer.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
          results.features.map(function (feat) {
            let id = feat.attributes['id'];
            let opt = document.createElement('input');
            opt.type = 'checkbox';
            let label = document.createElement('label')
            label.innerHTML = id;
            opt.className = 'id-item visible-id';
            opt.setAttribute('data-id', id);

            idElement.appendChild(opt);
            idElement.appendChild(label);

            selectedIDs[id] = false;
          });
        });

      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='id-filter' class='esri-widget'>
  </div>
  <div id='viewDiv'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

BTW, I added some logs for you to see what I consider import info of the events.

Last thing, I use an auxiliary dictionary to keep track of the visible features to filter. Another way to do it would simply to query all the checkbox and add the `id` to the filter if it is `checked`.